# google cloud ruby gem / running commands on behalf of oauth-authenticated user

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

Getting a bit lost in the diverse documentation endpoints ([here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/start/get_started), [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/), to name a few…)

[This one](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/)  is pretty usable for a given account by providing a json key as an environment variable.

The thing is, I just don't see how commands can be run on the behalf of a user authenticated via oauth — practically speaking, where do you specify the oauth user token ?

Thanks for sharing this insight

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[google-cloud-ruby](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby) (which you linked in your question) is designed to provide access via service account credentials, as you noted. For help with "lower-level" access in which you managing your own OAuth tokens, you might consider [google-auth-library-ruby](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby). However, if you can use a service account instead of a user account to use the higher-level access provided by google-cloud-ruby, I believe it's probably the best approach, as recommended in [Google Cloud Storage Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth):

> Due to the complexity of managing and refreshing access tokens and the security risk when dealing directly with cryptographic applications, we strongly encourage you to use a verified client library.